# vuex dispatching action in a component function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I want to dispatch an action and get the values passed into an input. When i directly dispatch an action on a button like this:

```
 <button type="button" @click="store.dispatch("foundJobs", {
    nameInputValue: nameFilter.value, 
    locationInputValue: locationFilter.value, 
    contractCheckboxValue: contractFilter,
});">Search</button>
```

everything works perfectly fine. But when i want to make an outer function to make it more clean and readable, instead of getting values of an input it gives me an input element as an output:

```js
const nameFilter = ref("");
const locationFilter = ref("");
const contractFilter = ref(false);

 <input type="text" placeholder="Filter by title, companies, expertise…"  ref="nameFilter"/>
 <input type="text" placeholder="Filter by location…" ref="locationFilter"/>
 <input type="checkbox" v-model="contractFilter" />

const searchResults = () => {
  store.dispatch("foundJobs", {
    nameInputValue: nameFilter.value, // console.log shows "input" element
    locationInputValue: locationFilter.value, // console.log shows "input" element
    contractCheckboxValue: contractFilter, // console.log shows "input" element
  });
};


 <button type="button" @click="searchResults">Search</button>
```

Why is that working like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the code in script and template parts is that [refs are unwrapped in templates](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#ref-unwrapping-in-templates).

It's a questionable practice to write the code in templates because this breaks the separation of concerns and makes a component less maintainable.

It should be:

```
 nameInputValue: nameFilter.value.value
```

The use of `unref` makes the intention more clear and emphasizes that `value` is accessed not on a ref but on some object:

```
nameInputValue: unref(nameFilter).value
```